# Switch without break but with validation enquiry

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logic, switch-statement

I'm wondering if there is any way to validade multiple times with a switch without breaks. For example:

```
 switch(case){
        case case1:
           //do things... many things.

        case case2:
           //do things... many things.

        case case3:
           //do things... many things.
           break;
}
```

What I want is for the code to run case1 and after case2 only IF case 2 is also approved. The reason I'm doing this with a switch instead of a case is because it's a situation where **one doesn't imply another** but might exist with it and vice-versa. Could be **none**. Like this:

```
A! Is B? 
   Yes! A and B
   No!  A
B! Is A? 
   Yes! B and A
   No! B
A? B? NOT A and NOT B
```

I know I could play around with ifs and conjunctions but I want to know if there is a simple way of doing this "directly".

Comment: Why must you use a switch statement? Just use if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem with simple `if`?

```
if (A && B) {
...
} else if (A) {
...
} else if (B) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there is any way to validade multiple times with a
>   switch without breaks

Without breaks you cannot use the **[switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)** correctly.

As for your solution you need if statement instead of switch

Simply like this:-

```
if (A && B) 
{
 //do many things here
} 
else if (A) 
{
//do many things here
} 
else if (B)
{
//do many things here
}
```